# Выполнить код на PHP через 5 минут

Tags: php

Добрый день. Есть код на PHP, который получает от пользователя необходимые данные и отвечает ему моментально. НО! Я хочу сделать так, чтобы пользователь получал ответ не моментально, а через 5 минут.

**Например:**
П - пользователь, PHP - PHP.
**Пользователь отправил данные**
П: x = 5.
**PHP отправляет ему сообщение о том, что ответ придет через 5 мин.**
PHP: Вы получите ответ через 5 минут.
**Проходит 5 минут, PHP отправляет ответ**
PHP: 2+x=7.

Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону копать, а лучше покажите на примере. В PHP совсем новичок, мало чего понимаю. Спасибо :)

Comment: Как-то php для этого мало подходит.

Comment: @Visman предложили записывать задачи в БД, а потом Cron выбирать те, которые старше 5 минут и выполнять их. Но мне показался что этот вариант не самый простой. Хочется услышать и другие варианты.

Comment: @MrFallen Это самый оптимальный вариант

Comment: @DaemonHK, и похоже единственный =)

Comment: Вопрос в том, как вы будите возвращать результат пользователю.

Comment: Если пользователь будет оставаться на странице все эти 5 минут то данные PHP скрипту можно отправлять через ajax и через js установить задержку отправки данных. Как писал Visman все зависит от того как будет возаращатся результат.

Comment: Как жаль... Как жаль... Ладно, буду пробовать. Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Заводим временное хранилище данных. Для этого вполне подходят сессии: http://php.net/manual/ru/book.session.php
2. В момент отправки информации пользователем на сервер сохраняем его информацию в этом временном хранилище, а также сохраняем там отметку текущего времени (или ещё лучше — отметку времени в будущем, когда мы скажем ответ): http://php.net/manual/ru/function.time.php
   Тут скрипт придётся завершить и вернуть пользователю что-то. Например, сказать, что «приходи через 5 мин»;
3. При очередном вызове скрипта первым делом проверяем, есть ли в хранилище информация. Если она есть, смотрим на отметку времени, пора ли её обрабатывать. Если да, возвращаем ответ.

Вот как-то так.